# Cannot display icons on webpage

Tags: google-chrome

When Chrome is being used, the icons on webpage cannot be displayed: 
[image] 
But there is no such issue on IE 10: 
[image]

I am using Google Chrome - Version 29.0.1547.76 m. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does the same issue occur in Chrome with no plug ins (run in incognito mode)

Comment: Check the location of the icons, are they on another host or under https and not http perhaps.

Comment: Good suggestion! solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Disable the following Extension in Chrome: 
[image]

Now is okay:
[image]